# prop checked does not work - special case

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, prop

Why when you click on the first button does not checked? Why when referring to the same checkbox one script does not work while the other does it correctly?

```js
$('.button1').click(function(event) {
  //console.log("click1");
  $('#table1 .checkbox1').prop('checked',true);
});
$('.button2').click(function(event) {
  //console.log("click2");
  $('.checkbox1').prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" />
  <input type="button" class="button1"  value="Checked1" />
  <input type="button" class="button2"  value="Checked2" />
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the browser is cleaning your markup, and removing `<table id="table1"></table>` (because it's not valid markup for a complete markup -- `input` cannot be a direct child of `table`).

As such, your selector (`#table1 .checkbox1`) does not match any elements. Your rendered markup looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" />
<input type="button" class="button1" value="Checked1" />
<input type="button" class="button2" value="Checked2" />

<table id="table1">

</table>
```

Image for reference from Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

Comment: I do not want to remove it from the table, I want to know why the buttons if they refer to the same checkbox one works and the other does not

Comment: @SamirLlorente No, I am not suggesting that *you* remove the table... Look at how the browser is rendering your markup. It's not valid, so the **browser** is rendering your `input` elements *outside* of the table, and thus your selector is not valid.

Comment: why said selector is invalid, any explanation?

Comment: I think you have not understood me, how would you do to select the checkbox inside table, but specifying the table with the id

Comment: @SamirLlorente make the table markup valid (by adding `<tr>` and `<td>`).

Answer (score 1):

While rendering the above html there is no `input` element inside `<table id="table1">` so your first button did not work. When you remove `#table1` selector form your code it will work. Or you need to add valid markup, for that simply change `table` to `div`.

```js
$('.button1').click(function(event){
  //console.log("click1");
  $('#table1 .checkbox1').prop('checked',true);
});
$('.button2').click(function(event){
  //console.log("click2");
  $('.checkbox1').prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="table1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" />
  <input type="button" class="button1"  value="Checked1" />
  <input type="button" class="button2"  value="Checked2" />
</div>
```

OR

```js
$('.button1').click(function(event){
  //console.log("click1");
  $('.checkbox1').prop('checked',true);
});
$('.button2').click(function(event){
  //console.log("click2");
  $('.checkbox1').prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" />
  <input type="button" class="button1"  value="Checked1" />
  <input type="button" class="button2"  value="Checked2" />
</table>
```

To work with table id

```js
$('.button1').click(function(event){
  //console.log("click1");
  $('#table1').parent().find('.checkbox1').prop('checked',true);
});
$('.button2').click(function(event){
  //console.log("click2");
  $('.checkbox1').prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" />
  <input type="button" class="button1"  value="Checked1" />
  <input type="button" class="button2"  value="Checked2" />
</table>
```

Comment: Please upvote answers already posted, rather than duplicating them.

Comment: @BenM Ok sure, Was typing and when post answer there was already one answer.

Comment: I know that this way it works, I ask why it does not work if the two buttons have reference to the checkbox

Comment: @SamirLlorente your code does not work because, there is no child element with class `checkbox1`  inside `table1` id element while rendering in browser.

Comment: You're sure @5740382 because if I make an attribute change it works fine

Comment: @SamirLlorente yes If you changed `table` to `div` it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171110/discussion-between-5740382-and-samir-llorente).